# how to calculate numbers in tcp server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have an assignment on c language with socket programming nd i dont know how to start
what that i asked to do is to write a TCP server with SELECT() function (not FORK())
the server needs to caculate the sum of N numbers that given by clients that connected to this server. 
the server need to print the N biggest numbers and the ip address of the client that send this number
the client connect to the server with the telnet service in terminal

i have already the TCP server but i dont know how to get numbers that send by clients.
thank you for your help

Comment: Did you try `man select` ?

Comment: Do you also have to write the clients? If so, what have you tried to `send()` the numbers? If you haven't written the clients, have you been given a description of what format the message you will `recv()` the values on the server will be in?

Comment: I don't need to write the clients, they connect with standart telnet. but every client that connect send me some number and i need to put it on array (this is the N) and then to calculate the biggest number online so if other client send other number i need to check again if the max hasn't changed

Comment: see for [this][1] sites for mote information.


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/593037/tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers

Answer (score 1):

To use a telnet server you need to bind a socket to a port number. The standard telnet port is 23. As you already have the server part, clients connect to the server; I'll send you the part that read the numbers. Copy it and paste to your program. To use it just call the ProcessConnection() function with the socket you get from the accept.

```
// Some "special" characters definitions
#define RETURN 13
#define NEWLINE 10
#define ESCAPE 27
#define BACKSPACE 8

// this is the max numbers that can be accepted per session
// you may change to do it dynamically, pointers and malloc, case you want to.
#define MAX_NUMS 250
int theNumbers[MAX_NUMS];

// To do the echo of remote typed chars
int doEcho = 0;

// return the sum of the Int theNumbers
int sumThemUp(int count)
{
    int sum=0, i=0;
    for (i=0; i < count; i++) sum+=theNumbers[i];
    return sum;
}

// return the biggest number
int getBiggest(int count)
{
    int ret=0, i=0;
    for (i=0; i < count; i++)
        if (ret < theNumbers[i]) ret = theNumbers[i];
    return ret;
}

// return the smallest number
int getSmallest(int count)
{
    int ret=0, i=0;
    for (i=0; i < count; i++)
        if (ret == 0 || ret > theNumbers[i]) ret = theNumbers[i];
    return ret;
}

void ProcessConnection(SOCKET wConSock)
{
    fd_set sfds;
    struct timeval timeout={0, 0};
    char actNum[12];
    int numNums=0;
    char ch;

    char  * WelcomeMessage1 = "Welcome to my telnet emulator\r\n";
    char  * WelcomeMessage2 = "Please type in a number and press enter\r\n";
    char  * WelcomeMessage3 = "To end the session press the Esc key\r\n";
    char  * WakeUpMessage = "Are you sleeping?, common wake up!!\r\n";
    int sentSleep=0;

    send(wConSock, WelcomeMessage1, strlen(WelcomeMessage1), 0);
    send(wConSock, WelcomeMessage2, strlen(WelcomeMessage2), 0);
    send(wConSock, WelcomeMessage3, strlen(WelcomeMessage3), 0);
    memset(actNum, 0, sizeof(actNum));
    memset(theNumbers, 0, sizeof(int) * MAX_NUMS);

    int KeepOnReading = 1;
    while (KeepOnReading)
    {
         FD_ZERO(&sfds);
         FD_SET(wConSock, &sfds);
         timeout.tv_sec=60; // 1 minute
         timeout.tv_usec=0;

         switch (select(1, &sfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout))
         {
            default:
                // there are errors in the socket, close it and quit
                close(wConSock);
                return;

            case 0: // time out has elapsed
                if (!sentSleep) send(wConSock, WakeUpMessage, strlen(WakeUpMessage), 0);
                sentSleep=1;
                break;

            case 1: // socket has data, let's read it
                if (recv(wConSock, &ch, sizeof(ch), 0) == sizeof(ch))
                { // got a char, let's see it
                    switch (ch)
                    {
                        case '0':
                        case '1':
                        case '2':
                        case '3':
                        case '4':
                        case '5':
                        case '6':
                        case '7':
                        case '8':
                        case '9':
                            if (strlen(actNum) < 10) strncat(actNum, &ch, 1);
                            if (doEcho) send(wConSock, &ch, sizeof(ch), 0);
                            sentSleep=0;
                            break;

                        case BACKSPACE:
                            if (strlen(actNum)) actNum[strlen(actNum)-1] = '\0';
                            if (doEcho) send(wConSock, "\b", 1, 0);
                            break;

                        case ESCAPE: // Esc
                            KeepOnReading=0;
                            break;

                        case RETURN:
                            if (doEcho) send(wConSock, "\r\n", 2, 0);
                            if (strlen(actNum))
                            {
                                theNumbers[numNums] = atoi(actNum);
                                if (theNumbers[numNums] > 0 && numNums < MAX_NUMS) numNums++;
                                memset(actNum, 0, sizeof(actNum));
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;
       }
    }
    char text[64];
    sprintf(text, "\n\n\r  Numbers entered:%10d\r\n", numNums);
    send(wConSock, text, strlen(text), 0);
    sprintf(text, "   Sum of numbers:%10d\r\n", sumThemUp(numNums));
    send(wConSock, text, strlen(text), 0);
    sprintf(text, "  Smallest number:%10d\r\n", getSmallest(numNums));
    send(wConSock, text, strlen(text), 0);
    sprintf(text, "   Biggest number:%10d\r\n", getBiggest(numNums));
    send(wConSock, text, strlen(text), 0);
    strcpy(text, "\r\n\nPress any key to quit...");
    send(wConSock, text, strlen(text), 0);
    recv(wConSock, &ch, sizeof(ch), 0);
    close(wConSock);
}
```